# how to use string values as axis ticks properly in d3js? Not able to map data correctly can't figure out whats wrong in this code

Tags: javascript, css, csv, d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to D3. In my scatterplot i need to plot usernames for y-axis but data and axis tick values are out of order can anybody help me find out what's wrong with this code ?

Full link to my code : [Scatterplot code](https://github.com/bhargavavn/scatterplot_pann)

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? You can sort the y-axis tick values when you input them: `y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.user; }).sort());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything major in your code.  A couple of things:

1.) The sorting on your y-axis is fine.  It's sorted in the order they appear in your data.  As @mdml says in the comments, you can sort them differently if you desire.

2.) You have an "odd" point in your data.  Everything is occurring around `Nov-27-2014-12:33` except for one point on the 28th.  This is causing `d3` to pick a larger range for the x-axis and plotting most your data points on top of each other.

3.) You should probably "center" your points in relation to you y-axis:

```
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.user) + y.rangeBand() / 2; })
```

Here's an example tweaking some [things](http://plnkr.co/edit/M66HlmnHhhlos4kSAZ4p?p=preview).